# Chamar action Get que retorna uma view por jquery ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Preciso abrir a view create ao clicar em um botão, como realizar isso por Jquery?

> Botão

```
<div class="col-md-3">
            <button id="btnNovo" class="btn btn-info form-control" style="width: 200px"> Novo </button>
        </div>
```

> Script

```
 <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {


            $('#btnNovo').click(function () {                

            });

            $("#filtro").on("keyup", function () {
                var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                $("#myTable > tr").each(function () {
                    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

> Action

```
// GET: Pais/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.cadastradoComSucesso = false;
            ViewBag.cadastroComErro = false;

            PaisModel paisModel = new PaisModel();
            paisModel.Ativo = true;
            paisModel.DataCadastro = DateTime.Now;
            paisModel.UsuarioCadastro = "USUARIO CADASTRO";

            return View(paisModel);
        }
```

Comment: Se você pretende "abrir" a view completa, porque não faz uma requisição normal pelo browser? Por que usar jQuery?

Comment: Como seria essa forma @LINQ?

Comment: Colocar um href no Button ?

Comment: Criar um link e chamar a URL que vai disparar a _action_ e retornar a _view_.

Comment: Button não pode ter href, mas é esse o caminho. Use uma tag `a` e coloque o href

Comment: Esta correto assim? Pois o visual studio da um aviso dizendo que não pode ter um button dentro da tah <a>

Comment: <a href="@Url.Action("Create","Pais")">
                <button id="btnNovo" type="button" class="btn btn-info"> Novo </button>
            </a>

Comment: Não pode ter um botão (`<button>`) dentro de uma âncora (`<a>`).

Comment: @LINQ, poderia me dizer qual a melhor forma, se puder colocar um exemplo ficaria muito grato.

Comment: É que eu não sei o que você quer fazer, sua pergunta não especifica nada. Você quer "abrir um link" usando um botão. Isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo amigo, tenho um botão chamado novo em uma página que listo todos meus registros, e quando clico nele, quero chamar a action Create (GET), que me traz a view de cadastro, entende ?

Comment: É só usar CSS pra âncora ter aparência de botão.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com base nos comentários, o que você quer é usar CSS pra âncora (`<a>`) ter aparência de botão (`<button>`).

```css
.btn {
  appearance: button; /* CSS3 */    
  -webkit-appearance: button; /* Safari and Chrome */
  -moz-appearance: button; /* Firefox */
  -ms-appearance: button; /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-appearance: button; /* Opera */
  cursor: default;
  padding: 5px 15px; 
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a class="btn" href="http://www.google.com.br">Sou um botão</a>
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, pra mim eu precisava usar a tag <button>, e não utilizar direto a tag <a>